# Spring RestTemplate: Read chuncked response

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, chunked

I'm using Spring RestTemplate to write a RESTful client.
I need to intantiate the HTTP Chunk mode on client side, so I can read chuncked data sent by the server I'm calling.

Can anyone help me how to do that? I've already searched on the internet for something that looks like what I need to do, but it didn't help.
Can you, at least, put me on some direction? and I'll will try to do it on my own :)

I need to do something like this:

```
ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0L, //
        TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
    executorService.execute(() -> {
       ChunkedInput<JsonNode> chunkedInput = null;
       JsonNode chunk = null;
       while (true) {
        try {
           chunkedInput = getJsonNodeChunkedInput(privatePollingUrl);
        } catch (CtiAlcatelException e) {
           logger.error("Getting Json Node Chunked Input refused", e);
        }

        while ((chunk = chunkedInput.read()) != null) {
           logger.debug("-- Next chunk received: {}", chunk);
           try {
            processEvent(chunk);
           } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error occured while processing chunk {}", chunk, e);
           }
        }

        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
           logger.info("Chunk thread interrupted");
           Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
           chunkedInput.close();
        }

        logger.debug("-- Restarting the chunk");
       }

    });

    private ChunkedInput<JsonNode> getJsonNodeChunkedInput(String privatePollingUrl) throws CtiAlcatelException {
        logger.trace(">> getJsonNodeChunkedInput() > Got param: {}", privatePollingUrl);

        final Response response = restfulService.get(privatePollingUrl, alcAdminCredential.getCookie(), null);
        ChunkedInput<JsonNode> chunkedInput = response.readEntity(new GenericType<ChunkedInput<JsonNode>>() {
        });

        logger.trace("<< getJsonNodeChunkedInput() < Returning: {}", chunkedInput);
        return chunkedInput;
       }
```

This is done using Jersey client.
Thank you very much